# Unable to customize user registration with djoser

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, djoser

I have being using djoser with django to handle register and login. I have no issue configuring the default register field (username, email, password and re_password).
But now I want to customize the register field and add `gender` and `hobby`. However, I keep getting the following error when I try to register another user with these additional fields that djoser
does not provide by default.

```
user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
TypeError: UserManager.create_user() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'gender', 'hobby'
```

The error is coming from the function in models.py file for creating new user shown below:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, email, gender, hobby, password=None, **extra_fields):
        if username is None:
            raise ValueError(_('Username is required'))
        if email is None:
            raise ValueError(_('Enter a functional email address'))

        if gender is None:
            raise ValueError(_('Provide your gender'))

        if hobby is None:
            raise ValueError(_('Enter hobby'))


        user = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(email) **extra_fields)
        user.username=username  
        user.gender=gender, 
        user.hobby=hobby
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self,username, email, gender, hobby, password=None):
        if password is None:
            raise ValueError(_('Please enter your password'))

        user = self.create_user(email=self.normalize_email(email))
        user.username=username 
        user.gender=gender, 
        user.hobby=hobby
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save()
        return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=25, unique=True, default='')
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    hooby = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

serializers.py

```
class UserCreateSerializer(UserCreateSerializer):
    class Meta(UserCreateSerializer.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = (
            'id', 
            'username', 'email',
            'gender', 'hobby',
            'password'
            )
```

settings.py

```
djoser = {
'SERIALIZERS': {
        'user_create': 'accounts.serializers.UserCreateSerializer',
        'user': 'accounts.serializers.UserCreateSerializer',
        'current_user': 'accounts.serializers.UserCreateSerializer',
        'user_delete': 'djoser.serializers.UserDeleteSerializer',
    }
}
```

I have gone through the code several times I still can't find why I'm getting the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. added the field into the REQUIRED_FIELDS in the User model and problem solved.
just add gender and hobby into the REQUIRED_FIELDS

Answer (score 0):

one problem is for sure that you have "hooby" as field

Comment: Yeah, that was typo error when I was posting the question here. The error is still the same

Comment: do you have a full stack trace?